# Where can I find this unicode character?

Tags: user-interface, unicode

I'm looking to find a unicode character that looks like ≪ or ≫ but rotated 90º and 270º to use in a GUI to signify something can be dragged vertically.

Does anybody know of a character like this?

Comment: What framework/tools are you using? WPF, XWindows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

︽   PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET (U+FE3D)

︾   PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET (U+FE3E)

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are looking for unicode characters here you have all http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html

i dont know if there are ones that you are looking for but for example you have arrows in row 2B00 also i saw few eariler

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see there aren't any symbols that you want.
But it might be appropriate for you to use the varios other arrow symbols that are defined starting at U+2190 (←). For example U+21d3 is ⇓.
Under Windows you may use the `charmap` Tool with font set to Arial Unicode. Or have a look here: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8592

Answer (score 0):

I'll put [this](http://unicode-table.com) here.

Just in case ツ