# Limits to Swing's Unicode support

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, unicode

Not long ago [I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081150/where-can-i-find-this-unicode-character) attempting to identify a certain unicode character for use in a GUI.  I got the character I was looking for, but it didn't work in the Swing GUI I was building.

So, SO Community, I pose of you these questions:

What sort of limitations does Swing/Java have for Unicode support?  Are there certain subsets of unicode that are completely supported and what should I stay away from when designing in the future?

EDIT:  After applying the 'Arial Unicode MS' font as suggested by Alan Moore, everything seemed to clear up.  Seems odd that I should have to set a 3rd party font to make all the unicode characters show up though.

Comment: There are no limits. Java's String class supports all possible Unicode characters.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say it doesn't work?  Are you using one of these fonts? http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FE3D/fontsupport.htm

Comment: @Alan Moore I'm using the default font provided by Swing in Sun's JDK 1.6.0_20 on WindowsXP and when I apply "\uFE3D" a tiny box appears.

Comment: Is there any need to install additional language packs depending on your OS ? Installing East Asian Fonts on Windows solved the tiny box / rectangle chars issue. Is there a full Java solution without JRE or OS (language pack) modification ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally when glyphs don't display properly in a UI, it's because you're using a font that doesn't have that glyph, not because there is a problem with the unicode support in any toolkit you're using.  Very, VERY few fonts have all glyphs - you need to make sure you choose a font that has coverage in the code points you care about.

Answer (score 2):

See [Sun Java 6 fonts Supported Fonts](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/font.html) for details on the limitations of the logical fonts. Sun's choices were probably due to a mixture of pragmatism and licensing. Note that the documentation says you can provision [fallback fonts](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Fallback_font) by adding them to the JRE `lib/fonts/fallback` directory.

Comment: FYI: see the _Java Internationalization FAQ_ for more info: http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/intl/faq.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Java 1.6 should have support for all Unicode characters. IIRC 1.5 didn't have methods to handle multi-char UTF-16 characters (new APIs were added to 1.6).

The characters from the question you posted show up just fine in the Java editor I use. Make sure the font you're using supports that character; the built-in JDK fonts support a lot of characters, but definitely not all. Take a look at the java.awt.Font.canDisplay() methods.

Comment: 1.5 added support for Unicode 4.0, while 1.6 enhanced unicode regexps but is otherwise unchanged.  Every version of Java has had complete unicode character set support for the version of unicode that was current at the time. (There were a couple small bugs in 1.4.2 with bound latin-b and arabic presentation forms-b)